# Trying to get highcharts export to work on app engine

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-app-engine, highcharts

I am struggling to accept the terms and conditions on the npm install for the highcharts export library.

https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server

The library is installing as i get an error image that means i havent accpeted the t&c's.

I have tried adding the preinstall to the package.json.

```
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "export ACCEPT_HIGHCHARTS_LICENSE=y",
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
```

And with 1 and YES (it seems it only needs a value and doesnt actually check the content of the environment variable. https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server/issues/102#issuecomment-364921497)

Also i have tried setting the config variables in the package json.

```
  "config": {
    "ACCEPT_HIGHCHARTS_LICENSE": "1"
  },
```

I have also tried setting the environment variables in the app.yaml

```
env_variables:
  ACCEPT_HIGHCHARTS_LICENSE: 'YES'
```

None of these worked. I would be very grateful if anyone could help.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to test it on Google App Engine but on my local Windows machine in the package.json file of a project where export server is a dependency I set "install": "set ACCEPT_HIGHCHARTS_LICENSE='YES' && node ./node_modules/highcharts-export-server/build.js" inside scripts section. Could you try this one (on Macs use export instead of set).

Comment: ill try now. Thank you for replying :)

Comment: It didnt work. I still get the image saying the server has not been correctly configured.

Comment: I just tried using gcloud beta app deploy --no-cache to force a reinstall but it made no difference.

Comment: Forgot to mention that it does work in local host just not on app engine.

Answer (score 0):

Create a package.json like one below

```
//package.json
{
    "name": "HighchartsExportServer",
    "dependencies": {
        "highcharts-export-server": "2.0.24"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node index.js -enableServer 1 --port 8080 --logLevel 4"
    }
}
```

Add an index.js

```
// index.js

// include the exporter module
const exporter = require('highcharts-export-server');

//Set up a pool of PhantomJS workers
exporter.initPool();

exporter.startServer(8080);
```

In app.yaml add this in environment variables

```
env_variables:
    ACCEPT_HIGHCHARTS_LICENSE: 'YES'
    HIGHCHARTS_VERSION: 4.2.0 # highcharts version here
```